# Calculating centrality measures using NetworkX for a bipartite graph and Gephi

Tags: python, social-networking, networkx, gephi, bipartite

I am a naive Python programmer and using it for my network data, so pardon me if this sounds silly. I have a two mode network with individuals and organisations. I have this as an edge list saved as a CSV file that I import to python. I have managed to read the CSV, project the graph into a bipartite network and export the file to gephi. After doing this, I am calculating the centrality (degree, eigenvector, closeness and betweenness) for my one mode projected and weighted graph. My code is as follows:

```
organisation_nodes, individual_nodes = bipartite.sets(B)
individual_nodes = set(n for n,d in B.nodes(data=True) if d['bipartite']==1)
organisation_nodes = set(B) - individual_nodes
organisation_graph = bipartite.weighted_projected_graph(B, organisation_nodes)org = bipartite.projected_graph(B, organisation_nodes)
print nx.info(org)
#degree centrality
deg_cent = nx.degree(org)
between_cent = nx.betweenness_centrality(org)
print between_cent
eigenvect_cent = nx.eigenvector_centrality(org)
print eigenvect_cent
close_cent = nx.closeness_centrality(org)
```

I visualised the graphml file that I got from the projected network onto Gephi and calculated the centrality measures there. However, there is a discrepancy in the centrality values calculated by Gephi and NetworkX. Only the density and the degree centrality values match. Is there something wrong with my code? If not, why the difference?
Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: The definitions used in Gephi and NetworkX might be different.   Could you include a small example showing what you expect and why either Gephi and/or NetworkX doesn't produce that answer?

Comment: @Aric Thanks, I found that the difference was in the algorithms used by these software. However, the only issue that I have now is that NetworkX & Gephi match for Eigenvector centrality but the ranking in UCINET seems to be different. The algorithm seems to be the same, no values are normalised. Here I am more interested in understanding why the node ranking differs more than the value per se.

Comment: If you have successfully answered your question you might want to post the answer, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question.  Add more details to this question if it is not completely answered.

Comment: Hi @SrinidhiVasudevan, I'm having the same problem that you are having. I would like to know what's the difference that you found in Gephi and Python? And how did you solve your issue? Tks.